# Contact Form submit button positioning

Tags: wordpress, css, css-position, contact-form-7

This is my site:

http://cvkj.agencialosnavegantes.cl/

I have a contact form at the bottom of the page and i'm trying to put the submit button next to the text box, but i'm struggling a lot.

This is my initial css:

```css
#enviarbajo {
    background:url(http://cvkj.agencialosnavegantes.cl/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/paper-plane-2.png) no-repeat;
    background-color: #564585;
    width:40px; 
    height:40px; 
    padding:0px 0 4px 0; 
    border:none; text-indent: -1000em; cursor:pointer;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 5%;
    position: relative;
    left: 35%;
   
}
```

Report post
Posted Friday at 01:00 PM
Hello

This is my site:

http://cvkj.agencialosnavegantes.cl/

I have a contact form at the bottom of the page and i'm trying to put the submit button next to the text box, but i'm struggling a lot.

This is my initial css:

## enviarbajo {

```
background:url(http://cvkj.agencialosnavegantes.cl/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/paper-plane-2.png) no-repeat;
background-color: #564585;
width:40px; 
height:40px; 
padding:0px 0 4px 0; 
border:none; text-indent: -1000em; cursor:pointer;
border-radius: 0;
margin: 5%;
position: relative;
left: 35%;
```

}
Then i tried to position the button using media-queries, but i'm not able to put the button where i want

```css
@media (max-width: 768px){
   #enviarbajo {
    position: relative;
    right: 100px;
    }
}
```

Other media-query below:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #enviarbajo {
    position: relative;
    right: 50px;
    }
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: remove the left value in css for #enviarbajo.wpcf7-submit{ left: 0px; } then make the response output clear both like this .wpcf7-response-output{ clear: both; } so that, this message will not overlap to the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using a fixed width button there are 2 good options instead of using divs with 75% and 25% widths.
In both solutions use 40px as the button width.

#### 1st solution

For the first div use calculated width: calc(100% - 40px)

```
#footer-widgets form.wpcf7-form div:nth-child(2){
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
#footer-widgets form.wpcf7-form div:nth-child(2) > span{
  margin: 0;
}
#footer-widgets form.wpcf7-form div:nth-child(2) input{
  width: 100%;
}

#footer-widgets form.wpcf7-form div:nth-child(3){
  width: 40px;
}
```

#### 2nd solution

Use padding (40px) and absolute positioning of the button

```
#footer-widgets form.wpcf7-form {
  position: relative;
}
#footer-widgets form.wpcf7-form div:nth-child(2){
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
#footer-widgets form.wpcf7-form div:nth-child(2) > span{
  margin: 0;
}
#footer-widgets form.wpcf7-form div:nth-child(2) input{
  width: 100%;
}

#footer-widgets form.wpcf7-form div:nth-child(3){
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: The 1st solution is the best, the 2nd not so much. For the first solution, i wish the submit button was closer to the input type email, i tried giving it more pixels at the 

#footer-widgets form.wpcf7-form div:nth-child(2){
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

Like  

width: calc(100% - 100px);

But it stays the same.

Comment: I can see that you still have inline CSS for those 2 divs with width in percentage, like: <div style="width: 75%; float: left;">. You need to remove that or use **!important** to override the widths. You should also remove 'left: 35%' on #enviarbajo CSS.

Comment: Now is working fine!

But i didn't remove the inline CSS from the divs, because this make the button go down, i just removed the emove 'left: 35%' on #enviarbajo CSS

Answer (score 0):

This is definitive answer for this question, as contributed by Lukasz Mazan

```css
#footer-widgets form.wpcf7-form div:nth-child(2){
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
#footer-widgets form.wpcf7-form div:nth-child(2) > span{
  margin: 0;
}
#footer-widgets form.wpcf7-form div:nth-child(2) input{
  width: 100%;
}

#footer-widgets form.wpcf7-form div:nth-child(3){
  width: 40px;
}
```

with this you can have the submit button next to the e-mail box in every screen size.

Problem solved.